# Calculating the variance, mean, and autocorrelation of a time series.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, statistics

How can I  calculate the mean, variance, and autocorrelation function:
$$Y_t=5+Z_t+ 0.6Z_t-1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple moving average process. Do you know the definitions of mean, variance, and autocovariance? If so, attempt to apply them. Keep in mind that $Cov(Z_j,Z_i) = 0$ if $j\not=i$ as we assume the $Z_t$ is noise.

Comment: ok but what is the expectation of the constant?

Comment: got the first two could you show me the auto correlation

Comment: @Mali Sure. It's enough to show auto covariance. By definition $$\gamma(k) = Cov(X_t,X_{t-k}) = Cov(5 + Z_t + 0.6Z_{t-1},5 + Z_{t-k} + 0.6Z_{t-k-1})$$ Now we consider the case $k \geq 1$ (why?). Using the covariance result I mentioned above, and linearity in each argument you should be able to simplify this to $0.6Cov(Z_{t-1},Z_{t-1}) = 0.6Var(Z_{t-1})$ if $k=1$ and $0$ if $k>1$.